# When were the modern notions of work and energy created

Tags: physics, thermodynamics

Reading through Wikipedia says that Coriolis was the first to introduce the notion of work, described as *"weight lifted through a height"*.

Our modern conception of work is of a force that realizes a displacement. This is general and valid for most forces (I don't know if we can apply this in general relativity or quantum mechanics). The book I'm studying for thermodynamics says that Joule's experiments clarified the relationship between heat and work, moving on to the first law.

We now regard heat as energy and give it his name. I don't think they saw these concepts in the same light we do now. Energy is one of the fundamental principles all of physics is based on, and it has many faces: Vibrational, kinetic (translational and rotational), heat, potential, internal energy, etc. **When did work and energy they take the form we use now?**

The book is *"Mere Thermodynamics"*, by *Don Lemons*.

Comment: [Virtual work laws](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/793601557) certainly predate Coriolis, going all the way back to the Greeks and the law of the lever.

Answer (score 5):

Mainly in the work of Hermann von Helmholtz in 1847. But of course (as always) there was a long development before and after.
http://books.google.com/books?id=C1i4AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA114#v=onepage&q&f=false

Notice that Helmholtz did not use the word "energy". At the time of Newton (and even before) it was noticed that some quantities are preserved in the systems that obey Newton's laws (one of them is momentum, another energy, using modern terminology). But there was a long confusion about this, and discussions on what is really presevred: mv or mv^2 :-) Later, different forms of energy were discovered (energy of heat, for example). But it was Helmholtz who finally made an order in this and stated conservation of all kinds of energy together as a universal law of nature.

Remark. At the time of writing this paper, Helmholtz was a military doctor (physician).
When he published this paper, his commanders were very pleased that an officer does useful research
on "preservation of force" :-)

Comment: Do you know which work? :)

Comment: I'll upvote if you can prove that Helmholtz was the first.

Comment: @HDE226868: Yes, Helmholtz's _On the Conservation of Force_ (i.e., _Work_) is certainly when "work and energy…take the form we use now".

Comment: @Geremia Yes, but where's a source that says that?

Comment: @HDE226868 "Work moved from thermodynamics to mechanics with Rankine, Helmholtz, and Duhem in the XIX century." (_[History of Virtual Work Laws](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/793601557)_ by Danilo Capecchi, 2012, p. 11). Helmholtz's _[Über die Erhaltung der Kraft](http://books.google.com/books?id=C1i4AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA114#v=onepage&q&f=false)_ was first, being in 1847. Rankine's _Outilines of the Energetic Science_ was in 1855 and Duhem's first thermodynamics/energetics books were in the late 1880s to 1890s, his masterpiece, the _Traité d’énergétique ou de thermodynamique générale_, being in 1911.

Comment: This answer is a little too short right now; it could almost be posted as a comment. Could you please expand a bit? Especially the lack of references is problematic.

Comment: @HDE226868: It is always difficult (if possible at all) to prove that someone did something first. I entered my answer. If you know who did this earlier, you are welcome to challenge it. But notice: pasting something from Wikipedia or another source DOES NOT constitute a proof.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko The method of finding sources (note: I always use at least three, when possible) that explicitly state that a person was first is generally better than finding a source that simply states when a person did something. I admit that I am often guilty of that (btw, I never use Wikipedia and think it should not be used at all), but I think that finding sources that state that a given person was first is as close to a proof as one can reasonably get without finding a first-hand account (which would certainly be the best one can do).

Comment: HDE 226868: I disagree about Wikipedia. It contains a lot of useful info, in many cases it is correct.

Comment: Joule, Mayer, and Clausius were all involved. Helmholtz would not have made it into the top three on my list.

Comment: Everyone is free to compose his/her own list:-)