# Who invented the concepts of potential and kinetic energy?

Tags: physics

Who invented potential and kinetic energy ?

Was it Newton ?
Or someone else ?

I have the impression Newton used those ideas but they already existed.

Comment: See http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/414/when-were-the-modern-notions-of-work-and-energy-created/415#415

Comment: [Semi-related meta discussion](http://meta.hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/133/quality-of-question-on-hsm). @AlexandreEremenko I think you're right; it's a duplicate.

Comment: Downvote and duplicate ; so I remove.

Comment: I cant remove , So why does it have downvotes ?

Comment: I think people may have downvoted because it seems like a duplicate. I don't think it's a bad question. I advise you to keep it open for now. It might be re-opened later. By the way, you might want to change 'invented' in the title.

Comment: By the way, the "-1" is only the net vote count. There are two upvotes and three downvotes, so it seems like there aren't any upvotes.

Comment: The concept of energy is ubiquitous, but mathematically, I wonder if Lagrange is a the right answer to a slightly different wording: who first solved physics using energy at the fore-front of the analysis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a way, it goes back to Aristotle and his dual concepts of [actuality and potentiality](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-metaphysics/#ActPot). My quick description of them is as follows:

- **Potentiality:** Potentiality, or *dunamis*, is the stored ability an object has to do something or be something.
- **Actuality:** Actuality, or *entelecheia/energeia*, is what an object is doing or is at a point in time.

Now, these had broader definitions than the ones we use to day for potential and kinetic energy. For example, according to Aristotle, the potentiality of an object included all the forms it could take (e.g. clay could become a sculpture).

These are clearly not the same things as today's notions of kinetic and potential energy, but they were the precursors to our modern ideas.

Comment: In this vain, see "[Act, Potency, and Energy](http://www.thomist.org/jourl/2011/2011%20April/McLaughlin.pdf)" by Thomas McLaughlin.

Comment: @Geremia Looks like a good read.

Comment: Yes, McLaughlin's PhD thesis is: "[The Aristotelian definition of motion and the principle of inertia](https://search.proquest.com/docview/304773934)" ([PDF](http://garrigou.us.to/get/PDF/McLaughlin%2C%20Thomas%20J_-Aristotelian%20Def.%20of%20Motion%20%26%20Principle%20of%20Inertia_3904.pdf)), so he's a master on this how Aristotle's _dunamis_ and _energeia_ relates to the modern concepts of potential and kinetic energy etc.