# Reference needed about history of classical mechanics

Tags: experimental-physics, reference-request, classical-mechanics

Who discovered/ defined momentum and impulse?

Please, I want suggestions about materials/ books on the development of Classical mechanics? Something like a history of experiments.

Comment: Have you read [Newton's Principia](https://archive.org/stream/newtonspmathema00newtrich#page/n77/mode/2up)? Momentum (his "motion") is the second definition.

Comment: no, but I know that he differentiated the momentum to get f=ma but what does the momentum physically mean how it's originated

Comment: When I was growing up the two books that seemed most relevant on library shelves were these two books by Max Jammer (currently available as Dover reprints): [**Concepts of Force**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/048640689X) and [**Concepts of Mass in Classical and Modern Physics**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0486299988).

Comment: For Early Modern Physics, see Richard Westfall, [Force in Newton's physics: the science of dynamics in the seventeenth century](http://books.google.it/books/about/Force_in_Newton_s_physics.html?id=nqYNAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y) (1971).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro pls what do you recommend i should read first

Comment: I attempted to post an answer to this question, but was prevented from doing so by an impossible captcha. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245100/whats-with-the-captchas

Answer (score 2):

The formation of the modern notion of momentum is described in the answer to  [What was the vis viva controversy, including its philosophical aspects?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/596/what-was-the-vis-viva-controversy-including-its-philosophical-aspects/598#598).

As for the history of mechanics in addition to Dave Renfro's excellent suggestions there is Dover's [nice little book](http://books.google.com/books/about/A_History_of_Mechanics.html?id=jmKxffjQtasC) by Rene Dugas.

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning Dugas's book ☺